# Why does my image keep zooming in within my grid or flex boxes?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner web developer student. I am trying to create two columns and three rows of flex boxes within a grid container. I have text on one side with an image of a delicious looking pancake in the second flex box which is at the top right corner.

Even though I had the image set to 100% to fill in the box, my image keeps zooming in so that it only shows a partial image. Using different images, I spent quite a lot of time realigning the container and boxes and looked up multiple ways to resize and reposition the image but for some reason, it keeps zooming in. How do I get the image to zoom out evenly so that the user can see the full pancake image while it also fills in the entire flex box?

**Original Image:** https://www.koreanbapsang.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/DSC9846-350x350.jpg

`enter code here`**Code Pen:** https://codepen.io/rylew09025/pen/ZEWaNOj

Comment: object-fit could be what you search for : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see how to create a [MRE] that includes only the code needed (e.g. `<head>`, nav etc are unlikely to be connected to the problem) and [edit] your question to include the code directly in the question itself - external links are ok but only when the code is also included here, as external links can break or change over time, and making the question unhelpful for future users.